# How to append custom sql to Spring Data JPA insert/update

Tags: spring, db2, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, db2-400

According to [IBM's docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21676715), in order for me to do inserts/updates, I need to append some sql (`with NC` OR `with NONE`) to update and insert statements.

I am calling the `S save(S entity)` method on my CrudRepository to do the save. **Is it possible for me to extend this a bit to append the required sql?**

I know I can write my own custom insert/update statements, but it would be really nice if I could just append to the sql that gets generated.

Comment: That technote only applies if you get that specific error (SQL7008N) when the database runs on i-series.  Can you confirm your Db2 runs on i-series, and you get SQL7008N?

Comment: @mao Yes my DB2 is running on an i-series, and I am getting that error. Also, I don't have the option of enabling journaling.

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using?  If you are using the JTOpen driver, you should be able to use the connection property: transaction isolation=none

Comment: @jweberhard I am using the LUW driver, but I have tried your suggestion and that still gives me the same error. I am using `Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool`, and following their [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes), I have set the `defaultTransactionIsolation` property to `none`

Comment: With NC are just tricks to bypass the transactions and journal over the database.  I'm just saying.

Comment: @JimmyJutt The LUW driver does not support transaction isolation level none since that only exists on IBM i.   Can you try the JTOpen JDBC driver (https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/)?

Comment: @jweberhard by "I have tried you suggestion", I meant that I tried the JTOpen driver. Apologies for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to get the desired result by extending Hibernate's `EmptyInterceptor` and overriding the `String onPrepareStatement(String  sql)` method.

```
public class MyInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        if (sql.startsWith("insert") || sql.startsWith("update")) {
            sql += " with none";
        }
        return sql;
    }
}
```

I also had to specify this interceptor in my `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=fully.qualified.name.MyInterceptor
```

Please note that `EmptyInterceptor` implements the `Interceptor` interface, and the `onPrepareStatement` method has been marked as deprecated in the interface.

It is recommended to use the `StatementInspector` interface instead, but I couldn't figure out how to set this up using Spring Boot. So if you get that working, please share.

**Update**

You can specify your implementation of `StatementInspector` in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory.statement_inspector=fully.qualified.name.MyStatementInspector
```